# Custom string colors in statusline

Tags: statusline

This is my `statusline` setting:

```
:set laststatus=2
:set statusline=%{GetMode()}\ %n\ %#StatusLineY#%m%*\%#StatusLineR#%r%*\ %t\ [%o\ %l\,%c\ %p%%\]
```

and this is the GetMode() functiom

```
function! GetMode()
    let ms=mode()
    if ms == 'n'
        return 'NORMAL '
    elseif ms == 'i'
        return 'INSERT '
    elseif ms == 'v' || ms == 'V' 
        return 'VISUAL '
    elseif ms == 's' || ms == 'S'
        return 'SELECT '
    elseif ms == 'R' ||  ms == 'Rv'
        return 'REPLACE'
    elseif ms == '!' 
        return 'SHELL  '
    endif
endfunction
```

This setting works well and now I would like to have different colors for the stringsreturned by `GetMode()` function (and not the whole statusline).

**EDIT2**
So for example blue foreground color for 'NORMAL', yellow for 'INSERT' etc.
Is it possible to achieve this ? If so, how ?

**EDIT1**
According to comments given below, I tried to add the `autogroup statusline` as follows:

```
augroup statusline
autocmd!
autocmd VimEnter,ColorScheme * hi User1 guibg=#0a0a0a guifg=#0000ff
augroup END
```

and applying this small change to `GetMode`:

```
let ms=mode()
if ms == 'n'
   return %1*NORMAL\ %*
```

But this generates an **E15 INvalid expression** error.

Comment: Check `:h statusline` and `:h hl-User1..9`. Read the whole parts of `:h statusline`, everything is there.

Comment: I already tried to modify the `GetMode` function to return the highlighted function according to that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. I added the test to the original post. As you can see, in my case it doesn't work well.

Comment: No, you need to include the `%1*` in the `set statusline` part. It doesn't have any meaning otherwise. In my example in the link, you can see, I used `%1*` and `%2*` in the ex-command `set statusline` as it is suggested in `:h statusline`. That is to say, use `set stl=%1*%{get_mode()}%0*`

Comment: OK I understand I did not exaplained well. What I want to achieve is different color for each mode. Not one different color for the string returned by the `GetMode` function.

Comment: Your function needs to return a string, so ' %1*NORMAL %*' or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I post here my own solution:

```
function! ColorUser1ToGreen()
        hi User1 guifg=#00ff00 guibg=#0a0a0a gui=bold
endfunction

function! ColorUser1ToLightBlue()
        hi User1 guifg=#9494ff  guibg=#0a0a0a gui=bold
endfunction

function! ColorUser1ToYellow()
        hi User1 guifg=#ffff00 guibg=#0a0a0a gui=bold
endfunction

function! ColorUser1ToOrange()
        hi User1 guifg=#ffa239 guibg=#0a0a0a gui=bold
endfunction

function! ColorUser1ToPurple()
        hi User1 guifg=#a683ff guibg=#0a0a0a gui=bold
endfunction

function! GetStatusLineMode()
    let ms=mode()
    if ms == 'n'
        call ColorUser1ToLightBlue()
        return 'NORMAL  '
    elseif ms == 'i'
        call ColorUser1ToYellow()
        return 'INSERT  '
    elseif ms == 'v' || ms == 'V' 
        call ColorUser1ToOrange()
        return 'VISUAL  '
    elseif ms == 's' || ms == 'S'
        call ColorUser1ToOrange()
        return 'SELECT  '
    elseif ms == 'R' ||  ms == 'Rv'
        call ColorUser1ToPurple()
        return 'REPLACE '
    elseif ms == '!'
        call ColorUser1ToPurple()
        return 'SHELL   '
    else
        call ColorUser1ToGreen()
    endif

endfunction

:set laststatus=2
:set statusline=%1*%{GetStatusLineMode()}%*\ %n\ %#StatusLineY#%m%*\%#StatusLineR#%r%*\ %t\ [%o\ %l/%L(%p%%)\ %c\ \]
```

Perhaps there are better solutions, but this fit my preferences.

Comment: calling a `:hi` command while evaluating the statusline is not a good thing to do. This might cause additional redraws. Better, use a dedicated `User` highlighting for each mode, so you can initialize the User highlighting only once and do not need to re-create them over and over

Comment: How many User colors can we define? Docs say that only 10 of them - is there any hack for creating more?
Also, having %#someHIname# is not sufficient because to actually change statusline, every time is has to be defined from scratch, using new colors. How to hack this properly and cleanly?